# Apple bluetooth keyboard insecure connection?

Tags: bluetooth, apple, keyboard

From time to time, I see this dialog box pop up on my MacBook Pro screen. It typically happens as the computer wakes up from sleep.

[image: popup message]

> Magic keyboard is trying to connect using an unsecured Bluetooth connection. Unsecured Bluetooth accessories can be used to control your computer or gain access to your data.

At this point, the bluetooth keyboard is still connected. Usually, I select "Don't Allow" in that dialog box, after which the bluetooth keyboard is no longer connected. Then I go to Settings and select the device and connect.

I am partially aware of some problems with bluetooth devices. Is this something I need to worry about, especially given that an Apple computer is complaining about an Apple keyboard. Could this particular keyboard be "special"?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your keyboard is trying to establish an **unencrypted connection**.

This allows any attacker (with physical proximity) to sniff the connection with the keyboard and logging the keys, thus enabling him to steal passwords and login information.

An attacker could also hijack the connection and start controlling the computer as if he had the keyboard in his hands.

Such things can be achieved by using tools such as https://github.com/virtualabs/btlejack

You can fix this by **pairing** the keyboard with your mac.

Try forgetting the keyboard using the Bluetooth menu, then connect the keyboard using a physical USB cable, this should initiate a secure connection.

Comment: Currently experiencing this problem right now. I plug the keyboard in and it connects and then I unplug it and instantly it disconnects and tries to establish an insecure connections once again. Brand new(ish) keyboard (maybe 2 weeks old) and first time with this issue in spite of CPU sleeping daily for about 1 hour or so. Will run with cable until I figure this out...